# Is there any chemical database written for python?

Tags: python, chemistry

I write script which needs to know atomic mass of tin. Is there a python database which has such info?

**Edit**:

`periodictable` is nice, but some libs are more rich in data. For example `gperiodic` program.

Comment: It's `118.710` according to wikipedia. Just put that in your script?

Comment: I know, but suppose I'll need something else, and suddenly - I should calculate the same for lead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have simply googled before asking. But anyway, you might find this useful: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/periodictable. Below is an example straight out of the page.

```
>>> from periodic import element
>>> hydrogen = element('hydrogen')
>>> hydrogen.mass
1.0079
```

Answer (score 6):

Not python specific, but the [Blue Obelisk data repository](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bodr/) hosted at Sourceforge is a comprehensive repo of chemistry data in XML format, in case that is of any use to you (or anyone else finding this).

Comment: I've built the sources (bodr-9). Almost no docs are found. I'll try to parse it into python using some xml parsers - to check what kind of data it possess. Or perhaps I'll first convert it to json.

Answer (score 4):

A periodic table and a true chemical database are quite different I suggest you to change the title of your question! There are more then 90 million organic and inorganic substances in [CAS](http://www.cas.org/content/at-a-glance) database! A chemical database written completely in Python is not the best choice at all to deal with so many records and would be tremendously slow!

It is better to use a python wrapper to allow to use Python to access an external chemical database  I like [chemspipy](http://chemspipy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) the Python wrapper for ChemSpider. It is easy to install with Pip but you need to register  (but it is free) to RSC.

Here a little example:

```
In [1]: from chemspipy import ChemSpider

In [2]: cs=ChemSpider('Here goes your personal code')

In [3]: tin=cs.simple_search('tin') #I use simple_search because search doesn't work for me

In [4]: print tin
[Compound(4509318)]                        

In [5]: tin[0].molecular_formula
Out[5]: u'Sn'

In [6]: tin[0].molecular_weight
Out[6]: 118.71
```